# How do I plot a 3D Vector function, that only has one variable?

Tags: plotting

So I have a vector-valued function

$$ r(t) = \langle \cos(t), \sin(t), \sqrt{t}\rangle $$

I am trying to plot the function over the interval  $ 0 \le t \le 4 $.

This is what I have for right now.

```
k[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], Sqrt[t]};

Plot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], Sqrt[t]}, {t, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: ParametricPlot3D instead of Plot3D.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Graphics3D` combined with `Arrow`:

```
  f[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], Sqrt[t]}
  dt = 0.2;
  table = Table[Arrow[{f[t], f[t + dt]}], {t, 0, 4, dt}];
  Graphics3D[table]
```

[image]

Or:

```
ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]